# display twitter compose tweet pages through an iframe

Tags: javascript, twitter, socialshare

so i have kind of a strange problem, I am in the process of building my own tweet button which is simple enough just using a link that resembles this `<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=YOUR-TITLE&url=YOUR-URL&via=TWITTER-HANDLE">`

now this as a link works just fine even with the dumby data prvided the problem is i would really like this page to open in an iframe on my site.. but twitter and other social networks have disabled this capability I am woundering if anyone know's a way i can use some sort of iframe or other tech including I assume an oauth and api which will alow me to send write, and display a tweet that the user can send inside my sight ?

as just using this returns an empty frame

```
<iframe src="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=YOUR-TITLE&url=YOUR-URL&via=TWITTER-HANDLE">
 </iframe>
```

anyhelp on how or even if I can do this or even a site I can check out that allows me as a user to do this would be greatly appreciated
(just a note I dont wish to tweet on a user behalf but rather display a pre defined text's tweet that enable the user to send without leaving my site or opening a new window )

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's against their terms of service. I'm researching the same issue now and it looks like you need to setup 0Auth to get an access token and then use the API. I'll report back when I have the full answer.

Comment: Hey from what I can tell you are correc I ended up putting this aside as using the OAuth would make users grant access before tweet, which is another point of friction, something that the iframe was a hope to alleviate

Comment: Large sites like qz.com are just linking to the post page, the src part of the iframe, and using target="_blank". It isn't pretty but I suppose it keeps you from jumping through hoops. What I'm really curious about is how http://thenextweb.com does it. The really hate solutions like addThis and will do what I can to avoid them.